# Stored Procedure is returning different count than the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Please forgive me if I am overlooking something simple but I am beating myself up trying to figure this out. I am trying to conduct a count and when I run the following query in SQL, I get a value of 21 but when the stored procedure is run with the same parameters, it counts 20. What is wrong?

Normal Query

```
(SELECT Count(DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, f.date_entered, 101)) 
              FROM   de_urine f 
              WHERE  f.location = @Location 
                     AND f.date_entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
                     AND f.qc_status = 'passed')                  AS 'Passed'
```

Stored Procedure

```
USE [POCQC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UrineCompliance]    Script Date: 5/3/2018 3:18:09 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UrineCompliance] @Location  AS NVARCHAR(50), 
                                        @StartDate AS DATE, 
                                        @EndDate   AS DATE 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT Count(DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, f.date_entered, 101)) AS 'Failed', 
             (SELECT Count(DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, f.date_entered, 101)) 
              FROM   de_urine f 
              WHERE  f.location = @Location 
                     AND f.date_entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
                     AND f.qc_status = 'passed')                  AS 'Passed' 

      FROM   de_urine f 
      WHERE  f.location = @Location 
             AND f.date_entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
             AND f.qc_status = 'failed'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM   de_urine p 
                             WHERE  p.location = f.location 
                                    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, p.date_entered, 101) = 
                                        CONVERT(VARCHAR, f.date_entered, 101) 
                                    AND p.qc_status = 'passed')
  END
```

Comment: And `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Are you sure the conditions are the same? e.g. Same `@StartDate`, `@EndDate` and `@Location`?

Comment: You use the same alias `f` twice, in the inner and in the outer query. Could that lead to false bindings?

Comment: If you observe the missing record you'll probably work it out straight away. This is an obvious first step in troubleshooting - observe the individiual records.

Comment: Is there a chance that the server is in a different timezone to whatever is calling the stored procedure and you are somehow providing it different date parameters inadvertently?  Using `DATE` instead of `DATETIME` makes me suspicious an extra day is getting added somehow by your start and end being offset x hours of timezone difference from what you think you are passing to it.